# Processing a post form in php with get variables for function options

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have been trying this with no success.
I have a standard form but some of the form contains information that I don't want sent over GET.  This being said, I know how to submit a form with php or javascript but my problem is on the server side script.
The problem that I am having is that the module.php that is supposed to get the POST variables and insert them into the database has multiple functions for different forms. so the page is as such..

```
if(isset($_GET['page_state']){
$page_state = $_GET['page_state'];
}else{
echo "You proccessed this file wrong";
}

if($page_state == 0){
do this function($_POST['formvariable'],$_POST['formvariable'
}


if($page_state == 1){
do this function($_POST['formvariable'],$_POST['formvariable']
}
```

Is there a way to process a form with post and get variables? Or maybe set a post variable outside of the form in javascript and use a link for get variables? hanging `action="module.php?mps=0"` just causes and error and will not submit the form at all.

Without the get variable `module.php` does not know what function to look for and get.
I am not opposed to using external libraries, but any help would be nice.
any ideas?

Comment: and what is your html code?

Comment: There is no reason an `action` attribute cannot have a query string. You should post your form tag at the very least.

Comment: sorry for the delay, I have been out of town.  Putting a get variable in the form tag does not work, using something like this

Comment: <form method="post" action="module.php?mps=0">